# How to render a shiny-RMD as HTML Document?

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown

I've created an RMD which has a chunk with some data that I imported from an RDS document. I've made this data to be interactive using Shiny tools. In my browser, the html works perfectly, but when I try to create an html_document to send to the team I'm working with, the html is no longer interactive and the data vanishes. Please ignore the comments, they are in Portuguese.

Here's the chunk:

```
{r Dados, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
library(rmarkdown)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Configurar um espelho para o CRAN
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"))

# Carregar os dados específicos para MoM e YoY
mom_data <- readRDS("C:/Users/MOM.rds")
yoy_data <- readRDS("C:/Users/YOY.rds")

>! Criar interface Shiny com guias
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("%MoM-sa", value = "MoM",
               dataTableOutput("tabelaMoM")),
      tabPanel("%YoY-nsa", value = "YoY",
               dataTableOutput("tabelaYoY"))
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    # Renderizar tabela específica para %mom-sa
    output$tabelaMoM <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(mom_data)
    })
    
    # Renderizar tabela específica para %yoy-nsa
    output$tabelaYoY <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(yoy_data)
    })
  }
)
```

I have tried to convert it into a html_document using:

```
render(mydocument.Rmd, output_format = "html_document", runtime = "shiny")
```

I also tried to do Ctrl + S in my browser html but it still does not work. I am not sure what it is supposed to happen when we "knit" (it became "Run Document" when I started using shiny) the RMD, because when I created it, I did specify that I want an html document as an output. A message does appear in my my console/render:

> "Output created: C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp253Vw5/file50e87bb9401c/teste1.html"

but when I reach out to that file it just does not follow the pattern of the original RMD and it also does not contains the data.

Answer (score 0):

When seeking an interactive HTML implementation, I typically use `flexdashboard` to generate my markdown. There are some ways to integrate `Shiny` into them as well.

You can get a taste for how, with actual code tutorials, [here in a very nice site by Paula Moraga](https://www.paulamoraga.com/book-geospatial/sec-dashboardswithshiny.html).

And you can get a sense of [formatting and working with flexdashboards here](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/)

You can also get some ideas for themes, [to add styles to your html documents here.](https://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/articles/theme.html)

None of this is an instant fix for immediate HTML output. However in my experience it is worth knowing how to build these sort of applications with intention.

Comment: In the end I had to stop using shiny because it needed access to a server aind it wasnt practical for me. However, I end up using the usual 'datatable' function with some help from javascript codes that made it somehow "interactive" in the html, e.g. showing values when hovering. But thank you for your help, appreciate it!